# Creating a simple multiple users app in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, model

So I've created 3 different users: admins, developers, and project managers. When I use the individual signup forms for each of these users and log out, it works, but then I when try to use the login form, it seems to me that it's acting like the signup form. Because when I input the same user details as the one I just created into the login form, it throws up the built-in error message, `'A user with that user name already exists'` I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Here's what I have so far.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('admin', 'Admin'),
        ('developer', 'Developer'),
        ('project_manager', 'Project Manager')
    )
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

login and signupviews

```
class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # Render the login form
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        # Get the form data from the request
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        # Validate the form data
        if form.is_valid():
            # Get the username and password from the form
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            # Authenticate the user
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            # If the user is authenticated, log them in and redirect to the homepage
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                if user.account_type == 'admin':
                    return redirect('admin_home')
                elif user.account_type == 'developer':
                    return redirect('developer_home')
                elif user.account_type == 'project_manager':
                    return redirect('projectmanager_home')
                return redirect('home')

            # If the user is not authenticated, render the login form again with an error message
            else:
                form.add_error(None, 'Invalid username or password')
                return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})

class LogoutView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # Log out the user and redirect to the login page
        logout(request)
        return redirect('home')
    
class AdminSignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = AdminSignUpForm
    template_name = 'users/admin_signup.html'
    success_url = '/admin_home/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Create the user and log them in
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect(self.success_url)    
    
class DeveloperSignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = DeveloperSignUpForm
    template_name = 'users/developer_signup.html'
    success_url = '/developer_home/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Create the user and log them in
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect(self.success_url)
    
class ProjectManagerSignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = ProjectManagerSignUpForm
    template_name = 'users/projectmanager_signup.html'
    success_url = '/projectmanager_home/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Create the user and log them in
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

forms.py

```
class AdminSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Define the form fields for the admin sign-up form
    account_type = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial='admin')
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password']
        
class DeveloperSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Define the form fields for the developer sign-up form
    account_type = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial='developer')
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password']
        
class ProjectManagerSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Define the form fields for the admin sign-up form
    account_type = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial='project_manager')
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password']
        
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'password']
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
```

login template

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Where is that message coming from ? It's not in the code you have posted.